# Retrieve and append values from one table to another in MVC4 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4, EF5 and MySQL. I have a template  I will like to populate  Table A with when a user clicks on a link from view to controller.

Table A Template( 3 records)

```
 Title
 Body
 CountryId
```

Table A (might have other records present belonging to a different user)

```
 Title
 Body
 CountryId
 UserId
```

So I want to append a new set of 3 records acting as a template which will add the UserId of the currently logged in user to differentiate from other user records.  I dont know how to make this happen in the controller.  Thank you if you are able to help.

I figured out something  but not sure if this is the most efficient approach?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetATemplate(int CountryId)
        {
        var userId = MySqlWebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
        var temps = db.ATemplates.ToList();
        foreach (var temp in temps)
            {

            db.ATables.Add(new ATable() 
             { Title =  temp.Title,
               CountryId=CountryId,
               UserId= userId,
               Body  = temp.Body,
               DatePosted = DateTime.Now

              });
              }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You should think of it more object-based. I can't see what you are trying to do, but if you have one class (let's say the upper one) and you want to use objects of that class as a template for the lower one, you can inherit the first one and add properties to it. The latter object should accept the first object as constructor parameter. I suggest you take a look at some tutorials to get used to EF and ORM.

Comment: @Robert  Thanks I have templates A B, C  So a logged in user can select any.  The templates have pre-populated  common values (3 rows-  with values for Title, Body and CountryId) as a starter for the user to build on. There are other fields in the class A that the user will continue to build by editing rather than creating.

Comment: I think you should use Template having all fields (common as well as other fields). Just show common fields while creating & show both while editing.

Comment: @vaibhavshah thanks for your suggestion.  I have got a working  controller action to achieve that now.  Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your question at all...! However, every where in your mvc 4 app, you can get the username of currently logged in user with the following line:

```
string uname = User.Identity.Name;
```

I think that you show some `Template A`s in your view and you want to assign their values to the user which select them, and populate all those data into `Table A`, right...?

OK. To do so, change your action method like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetATemplate(int CountryId)
{
    var userId = MySqlWebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
    var temps = db.ATemplates.Where(t => t.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();
    foreach (var temp in temps)
    {
        if(!db.ATables.Any(a => a.UserId == userId && a.CountryId == temp.CountryId))
        {
           db.ATables.Add(new ATable() 
           {  
           Title =  temp.Title,
           CountryId = CountryId,
           UserId = userId,
           Body  = temp.Body,
           DatePosted = DateTime.Now
           });
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

I still haven't any idea to what this method does...! However I think it's what you want...

Comment: Thanks but my Problem is how do I retrieve  all records from  Template A  and add all to table A  for example

Comment: @Diin - As I said, I can't understand what you are trying to do... What is Template A? Where is Table A...??? try to show me the model of your table in your database, and what output you want to have...

Comment: I have edited my original question with controller code I have come up with  and  that works now.  When a logged in user selects a template(eg template A) it will copy  the values of the template to the main model(table A- this is common model for all users) and adds the logged in userId to the records.

Comment: Thanks for adding the checks I will give you a tick for your concern to help me out